# Setting up Hadoop in Pseudo-distributed mode in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hadoop, hdfs

I'm trying to teach myself Hadoop on my laptop. My objective is to get the pseudo distributed mode running.

I'm following the [guide](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Purpose)  from the Apache website to set up Hadoop and HDFS in Ubuntu, but I can't get it to work.  Here are the steps I have followed so far:

1) check Java version:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
java -version
```

returns:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-8u111-b14-2ubuntu0.16.04.2-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

2) obtain Hadoop 2.7:

```
wget http://apache.mirrors.tds.net/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.7.3/hadoop-2.7.3.tar.gz
cd /home/me/Downloads
tar zxf hadoop-2.7.3.tar.gz
mv hadoop-2.7.3 /home/me
```

3) link Hadoop to JAVA.

replace

```
export JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}
```

by

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")
```

in

```
gedit /home/me/hadoop-2.7.3/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh
```

4) add SSH:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
sudo apt-get install ssh
sudo apt-get install rsync
```

5) add `/home/me/hadoop-2.7.3/bin` and `/home/me/hadoop-2.7.3/sbin` to the PATH:

```
cd 
gedit .bashrc
```

and add:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/me/hadoop-2.7.3/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/home/me/hadoop-2.7.3/sbin
source .bashrc
```

7) Now, I'm trying to set up the Pseudo-Distributed Operation mode. Still 
 following the [instructions](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Configuration), I change `/home/me/hadoop-2.7.3/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml` by adding

```
 <property>         
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>         
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>    
 </property
```

in the `<configuration>` block and I change `/home/me/hadoop-2.7.3/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml` by adding

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
</property>
```

8) Following the instructions, doing:

```
hdfs namenode -format
```

seems to work (yields Y/N prompt and lot of texts on the screen).

9) start hdfs:

```
start-dfs.sh
```

also seems to work (prompts a couple of passwords).

10) Create the folder structure for input. Doing

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /user
hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/hduser/
hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/hduser/input/
```

works. But now, doing

```
hdfs dfs -put /home/me/Desktop/work/cv/hadoop/salaries.csv /user/hduser/input/
```

yields:

```
16/12/12 14:53:14 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /user/hduser/input/salaries.csv._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1571)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getNewBlockTargets(FSNamesystem.java:3107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3031)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:725)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:492)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2043)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1475)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:418)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1251)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:448)
put: File /user/hduser/input/salaries.csv._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
```

and

```
hdfs dfs -ls /user/hduser/input
```

doesn't show anything;(

## Edit:

After reading  Arduino Sentinel's answer, my  `hdfs-site.xml` file is:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
       <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
       <value>/home/me/Desktop/work/cv/hadoop/namenode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
       <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
       <value>/home/me/Desktop/work/cv/hadoop/datanode</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

and both `/home/me/Desktop/work/cv/hadoop/datanode` and `/home/me/Desktop/work/cv/hadoop/namenode` exist.

make sure that `/home/me/Desktop/work/cv/hadoop/datanode` and `/home/me/Desktop/work/cv/hadoop/namenode` are empty:

```
rm -rf  /home/me/Desktop/work/cv/hadoop/namenode/*
rm -rf  /home/me/Desktop/work/cv/hadoop/datanode/*
```

and now doing

`hdfs dfs -put /home/me/Desktop/work/cv/hadoop/salaries.csv /user/hduser/input/`

does not return an error message and doing:

```
hdfs dfs -ls /user/hduser/input
```

yields the desired result:

```
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   3 me supergroup    1771685 2016-12-20 12:23 /user/hduser/input/salaries.csv
```

Comment: Do you have `/usr/local/hadoop/bin` in your `PATH` environment variable? Please post the output of `echo $PATH`.

Comment: Added `/usr/local/hadoop/` to PATH (Thanks!). `echo $PATH` gives : `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/hadoop/bin`. But the script still does not run (though the error message is now different)

Comment: Can you post the contents of your Hadoop `core-site.xml` config file?

Comment: can you consider accepting the best answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `hdfs-site.xml` should have `dfs.namenode.name.dir` and `dfs.datanode.data.dir` properties that points to a local directory in order name node and datanode to start.

```
 <property>
   <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
   <value>/<local-dir path>/namenode</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
   <value>/<local-dir path>r/datanode</value>
 </property>
```

Comment: can `dfs.namenode.name.dir` and `dfs.datanode.data.dir` be just any directory with write/read privilige?

Comment: Changing temporary directory location changes the default for storage directories.
Which should also work.

Both the namenode storage directory and the datanode storage directory are defined relative to hadoop.tmp.dir so simply changing that directory will change both of the subdirectories. But this doesn't allow me to change back and forth without errors.

Comment: example it might be something like this

`<property>`
     `<name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>`
    `<value>file://${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/name</value>`
    `<description>Determines where on the local filesystem the DFS name node
      should store the name table(fsimage).  If this is a comma-delimited list
   of directories then the name table is replicated in all of the
    directories, for redundancy. </description>`
`</property>`

Comment: see [Hadoop hdfs default xml](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml)

Answer (score 3):

Try to give **namenode hostname/ip** for `dfs.namenode.rpc-bind-host` and `fs.defaultFS` than `localhost` in all the node of cluster.

Configurations to do:

```
<!-- core-site.xml -->
<property>         
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>         
    <value>hdfs://{namenode hostname/ip}:9000</value>    
</property

<!-- hdfs-site.xml -->
<property>         
    <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-bind-host</name>         
    <value>{namenode hostname/ip}</value>    
</property
```

---

I suspect you might be facing **connectivity or passwordless login issues** because of that it's **prompting you for password**. I'd recommend you to cross check these things in your cluster.

1. Check the datanode hostnames in slaves file which will be at `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR` and hostname resolving issues (`/etc/hosts`)
2. Check the connectivity(ping hostname/ip) and among the nodes in cluster. 
   Use this utility command to pass a command to all hosts in cluster from each node.

> **Tip:** `slaves.sh <command you want to pass all nodes in cluster>`

3. Test Password-less login among datanode and namenode.`ssh hostname/ip` includes `ssh localhost` as well.
4. Check the folder(`dfs.namenode.name.dir`, `dfs.datanode.data.dir` and `$HADOOP_INSTALL_DIR`) permission for Linux user which you are trying to start dfs.
5. When `start-dfs.sh` executed it **shows log location of each datanode** (helps finding FAILURE reason).

Let me know if there are issue around with them.

Comment: Sorry, is this for the pseudo distributed mode? I'm doing all of this on my laptop (not on a cluster). I was unclear about this. Is your answer still relevant, in light of this additional piece of information?

Comment: this is for fully distributed mode.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have HDFS properly set up and running. Follow [these instructions](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html) to get a single-node HDFS cluster running.

And, for the record, make sure your Hadoop bin directory is in your PATH.

Hint: Just because you can run `hdfs dfs -ls /` does not mean your HDFS cluster is running. The `fs.defaultFS` setting is missing, so you're seeing the files on your local filesystem instead of the HDFS. After setting `fs.defaultFS` to `hdfs://localhost:9000`, you must actually start the HDFS daemons. The link above give you step-by-step instructions on how to do that.

After starting HDFS, you will also need to start YARN too, in order to actually run MapReduce jobs.

Comment: Your HDFS namenode is not running, possibly your datanode too. Start them, or if they throw an exception, look in the logs to see what's going on.

Comment: Follow the instructions carefully. You must start the namenode and datanode daemons.

Comment: You need to be in the hadoop top-level directory when you execute the `sbin/start-dfs.sh`, in your case `/home/me/hadoop-2.7.3`.

Comment: `There are 0 datanode(s) running` that's the clue that something is wrong with your datanode. Have a look in the `logs` subdirectory for the datanode log to see what the problem could be.

Comment: (I've cleaned my comments since you have already addressed them). I have set `fs.defaultFS` to `hdfs://localhost:9000`. How do I start HDFS daemon? As I have put in my answer, I am following step by step your link but hitting a wall at `hdfs dfs -ls /user/hduser/input`

Comment: Your symptoms still point to the datanode not running properly, maybe also the namenode. Please post your hdfs-site.xml file as instructed by the answer by Arduino Sentinel. Make sure the directories specified there actually exist on your machine. Also post the log messages from these log files: hadoop-datanode*.log, hadoop-datanode*.out, hadoop-namenode*.log, hadoop-namenode*.out (actual names of the log files may vary on your machine)

Answer (score 1):

Few of the possible issues and fixes:

1. Check if datanodes are running.
2. Check the Hosts file(`/etc/hosts`). It should have:

   ```
   127.0.0.1 localhost
   ```
3. Few others:

   Try the `telnet localhost <port>` from your server.

   Try `telnet <server> <port>` from the clients.

   Follow the step in `https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused`.

Comment: There is a good chance its the third type of issue, if so then check your firewall, `iptables` and check if anything is blocking those ports.